# How to declare a cursor using dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, dynamic-sql

I would like to declare a cursor using below dynamic SQL but the below SQL fails when I try to compile it with in a stored proc. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

```
DECLARE selrec CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT countrycode FROM @InputTableName;
```

Error msg :-

```
Must declare the table variable "@InputTableName".
```

PS :- I declared the variable name and also I have set the value before building the cursor.

Comment: I think you are confused about what `dynamic SQL` is

Comment: The issue isn't the cursor, per se. It's that table *variables* are limited to their local scope. You need to use a temp table or something with even broader scope visibility.

Answer (score 0):

As an example:

```
declare

    var1    varchar2(100);
    table1  varchar2(30);
    x       integer;

begin

    if x = 1
    then
        table1 := 'tablename1';

    else
        table1 := 'tablename2'
    end if;

    var1 := 'select * from '||table1;

    execute immediate var1;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me (in a db with these two tables):

```
declare @i1 int=5
declare @a1 varchar(1000)
set @a1='select top 5 * from '
if (@i1 > 4)
begin
    set @a1 = @a1 + ' [dbo].[dts_source]'

end
else
begin

    set @a1 = @a1 + ' [dbo].[dts_references]'
end
select @a1
exec (@a1)
```

What SQL machine are you running under (

> execute immediate

is not SQL Server syntax)?